# motion of an electron near a conducting wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

An electron is ejected from the surface of a long thick straight conductor carying a current, initially in direction perpendicular to the conductor. The electron will:
a) ultimately return to the conductor
b) move in a circular path around the conductor
c) gradually move away from the conductor along a spiral
d) move in helical path with the conductor as the axis

According to me, $$mv^2/r=qvB\implies r=mv/qB$$ since B is the magnetic field due to the conductor, $B=\mu i/2\pi R$ where R is the distance from a conductor. So$$r=2\pi mvR/\mu qi$$
Since the force will always be perpendicular to the velocity, the electron moves in a circle. As the electron moves, $R$ increases since the electron has to move outwards first to complete the circular motion. As $R$ increases, $r$ also increases. So I think the electron should move away from the conductor along a spiral.

What is the correct answer?

Comment: there is a sin(theta) you are ignoring in the formulas for the lorenz force http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force . If the electron is along the lines of B it will move out  unaffected and only the random walk from scatters in the perpendicular to B direction will create a spiral along a B line

Comment: velocity of the electron is always perpendicular to B so there is no need to consider theta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Since the particle is an electron $F$ is in the opposite direction $v\times B$

You must be able to figure out the answer now.

Comment: the electron moves in a circle and as it moves B decreases. So the radius of the path increases, not decreases

Comment: You have some wrong picture in your mind, see the direction of force at various instances. The particle is coming towards the wire and not going away.

Answer (score 0):

(a) ought to be the correct option. Electron is a charged particle, and it emerges from the surface with a definite kinetic energy. The electron then, as you propose, would move in a circle, **but with constantly decreasing radius (a resultant spiral) ** The electron has got its acceleration vector directed towards the circles centre, and we know, that an accelerating charge loses its energy continuously, in the form of electromagnetic radiations. Thus, it is reasonable, that the electron comes back to the conductor, when all of its kinetic energy has been exhausted.

Comment: It would not move in a circle. It's not in a constant B field.